# Use Lagrange multiplier to find extrema of $f(x,y,z,t)$ subject to the stated constraints.

Tags: calculus, lagrange-multiplier

> Use Lagrange multiplier to find extrema of $f$ subject to the stated constraints.
>
> $f(x,y,z,t)=xyzt$
>
> $x-z=2$ and  $y^2+t=4$

My attempt:

Let $g(x,z)=x-z-2=0$ and $h(y,t)=y^2+t-4=0$

$\nabla f=\lambda \nabla g+\mu \nabla h$

$(yzt)i+(xzt)j+(xyt)k+(xyz)l=\lambda (i-k)+\mu (2y j + l)$

Therefore,

$xyzt=\lambda x$

$xyzt=2\mu y^2$

$xyzt=-\lambda z$

$xyzt=\mu t$

$x-z-2=0$

$y^2+t-4=0$

Now, we wnat to solve this system, and by add the first four equations, we have

$\frac{7}{2} xyzt=\lambda (x-z)+\mu (y^2+t)$

$=2 \lambda +4\mu=2(\lambda +2\mu)$

$xyzt=\frac{4}{7} (\lambda+\mu)$

Then,

$\lambda x= \frac{4}{7} (\lambda+\mu)$

$\mu y^2= \frac{2}{7} (\lambda+\mu)$

$\lambda z= \frac{-4}{7} (\lambda+\mu)$

$\mu t=\frac{4}{7} (\lambda+\mu)$

Now what can I do? Can I divide these equations by $\lambda$ or $\mu$ to find $x,y,z$ and $t$? But I don’t know what the value of $\lambda$ and $\mu$ it may be will zero!

Please help :) thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stationary points can be found as follows:

We have the following first order conditions:

$$yzt = \lambda \tag{1}$$

$$xzt=2\mu y\tag{2}$$

$$xyt=-\lambda\tag{3}$$

$$xyz=\mu \tag{4}$$

$$x-z=2\tag{5}$$

$$y^2+t=4 \tag{6}$$

From $(1)$ and $(3)$,

$$yzt=-xyt \iff (x+z)yt=0$$
From $(2)$ and $(4)$,
$$xzt=2xy^2z \iff xz(t-2y^2)=0$$

We consider the case where the objective function is non-zero.

$$x+z=0$$ and $$x-z=2$$

Then we have $(x,z)=(1,-1)$.

Also if $$t-2y^2=0$$

and $$y^2+t=4$$

Then we have $$2y^2=4-y^2 \iff y^2=\frac{4}{3}$$

$$(t,y)=\left( \frac83, \pm\frac{2}{\sqrt3}\right)$$

Remark: We still have to examine if the function can be unbounded.

If we let $x=2, z=1$, $t=4-y^2$, then the objective function becomes $2y(4-y^2)$, it is indeed unbounded.

Comment: Thank you so so so much prof.

Comment: Note that I haven't consider some stationary points, those are the ones that make the objective function $0$.